# How to default “View as” Device in Xcode - Main.Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

Problem: When i start a new project in xcode, my Main.Storyboard opens by default with Iphone Xr artboard. But i do all my testing and build for iphone Xs. Because of that i have to change the "view as" device option to iPhone XS and also while i run the project, i have to make the change.
[image: screenshot of where i want to set a default device]

What i need: to default a device so when i open xcode, i get that as my artboard.

Comment: When you create a new project then first time need to setting your simulator or screen sizes via size classes. After that every time when you reopen it. then xcode open your simulator or storyboard according your settings.

Comment: Hi, i am fairly new to iOS programming. Could you let me know how to change size classes. Is it some code i have to write or an option i have to select from preferences

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project then first time need to setting your simulator or screen sizes via size classes. After that every time when you reopen it. then xcode open your simulator or storyboard according your settings. 
Here you can look size classes tutorials. https://medium.com/@craiggrummitt/size-classes-in-interface-builder-in-xcode-8-74f20a541195